# PyQt4: QtWebKit display local file using the Qt resource system

Tags: python, url, resources, pyqt4, local

How would you display a local html file using the Qt resource system? The obvious `QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(":/local_file.html")` doesn't seem to be the correct syntax.

File mainwindow.qrc (before compilation)

```
<qresource prefix="/">
    <file alias="html_home">webbrowser_html/program_index.html</file>
```

File ui_mainwindow:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):    
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        #...
        self.WebBrowser = QtWebKit.QWebView(self.Frame3)
```

File webbrower.py

```
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
import mainwindow_rc

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setupUi(self)
        #...
        stream = QtCore.QFile(':/webbrowser_html/program_index.html')
        if stream.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly):
            home_html = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8(stream.readAll())
            self.WebBrowser.setHtml()
            stream.close()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`QUrl` requires a scheme, and for resources it is `qrc://`. Relevant part from the [docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/resources.html):

> By default, resources are accessible in the application under the same
>   file name as they have in the source tree, with a `:/` prefix, or by a
>   URL with a `qrc` scheme.
>
> For example, the file path `:/images/cut.png` or the URL
>   `qrc:///images/cut.png` would give access to the cut.png file, whose
>   location in the application's source tree is `images/cut.png`.

So, use this instead:

```
QtCore.QUrl("qrc:///local_file.html")
```

**Edit**

You are giving the file an `alias` (`alias="html_home"`):

```
<qresource prefix="/">
    <file alias="html_home">webbrowser_html/program_index.html</file>
```

Path is now `:/html_home`, not `:/webbrowser_html/program_index.html`

You should use:

```
QtCore.QUrl("qrc:///html_home")
```

Which would be in your case:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setupUi(self)
        #...
        self.WebBrowser.load(QtCore.QUrl('qrc:///html_home'))
```

(You should adjust the [ekhumoro's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12377738/843822) too, if you intend to use that. Also note that you are not setting the HTML of the page in your paste.)

Comment: @XianJacobs: Could you post how you use these solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Local resource files can be opened with `QFile`:

```
stream = QFile(':/local_file.html')
if stream.open(QFile.ReadOnly):
    self.browser.setHtml(QString.fromUtf8(stream.readAll()))
    stream.close()
```

Comment: @X.Jacobs. Your example code doesn't pass `home_html` to `self.WebBrowser.setHtml()`.